# Deploy Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider with WPF package

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have WPF application which I use Access Database engine 12.0 to read excel file.

In order to work this application correctly this database engine needs to be installed in the user machines. I want to install that if user hasn't install that in their machine.

How Can I achieve that with the click once deployment.

Comment: Considering all the [pain the Access Database Engine driver is causing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64) with Office 32/64-bit incompatibilities, it might be worth using a third-party component to import and export Excel files, if you plan to distribute your application to a wider public.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using WiX Toolset? (http://wixtoolset.org/)

You can accomplish what you're trying to do in a very simple way, and it's really easy to use.